# Is there a way to keep widgets the same between sessions?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm building out a Shiny App that needs to keep the widgets the same between sessions. So, if a slider is put at 0.20 at the end of a session, the next time the app is opened, it should still be at 0.20.

I was thinking about having a CSV file that you download at the end of your session that tracks the values of each widget, and then at the beginning of the new session, you upload the previous session's CSV file which could then change each widget to what the previous session's values are. But, is there a way to do this that's more elegant? I'm trying to prioritize user experience. The app will be hosted on shinyapps.io.

Comment: check this out https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html I had an app that I used the dropbox solution in the article. It worked well enough

Comment: ohh, did that help you save the values of widgets? I did see that page but when I looked into it it looked like it just saved the resulting dataframes.

Comment: I haven't attempted using bookmarks, but it's on my list to try: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html

Comment: I'm a fan of a local sqlite database ... it's "free" and fast; the hardest part is determining when to write to it ... every time something is changed? every minute? button-click?

Comment: create the widgets server-side and store the current value in a local data file (csv, xlsx, rds) and initialise the widget after reading the file.

Comment: It was a slightly different project, but it let the user save a big data file and come back to it later

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to thank you all for your solutions :) The bookmarkable state was super easy to implement, but it did not work with the username and password I had set up, so I had to find an alternative way to keep my app secure, but overall that was the easiest way to go about saving the states of the widgets.